# How can I stop the programme when user enters "stop" (c# console)

Tags: c#

[the question with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUvkI.png)

This is my code and I explained everything in the code.

```
Console.Write("If you write stop program will stop.");
        string a; 
        string b = "stop";

        a=Console.ReadLine(); //I try to get a value for my a string 

        for (int i = -3; i <= a.Length; i+=4) // try to read them with 4 length groups 
        {
            if (a[i] == b) //and my logic was like this if it see the stop it will stop but I couldn't write it.
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, however shouldn't `if (a[i] = b) ` be `if (a[i] == b) `?

Comment: `a[i] = b` will *assign* the value of `b` to `a[i]`. You surely want `if(a[i] == b)`.

Comment: what's the `for` loop about? If the user can write anything including the word "stop" then just search for that string within the input string (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-search-strings-using-string-methods). If they have to write _exactly_ "stop" and nothing else, then simply check if the string equals that, or not.

Comment: I send the question image that you can understand better. I tried to explain you are correct but still wrong syntax can't we use like this... And my other question is how to stop the program when user write "stop"

Comment: I would suggest re-reading / visiting some `C# Basics Tutorials` under stand the difference between `=` and `==`

Comment: @İSMAİLKARADAYI my comment gives you suggestions for that, depending on the precise requirement, which wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes, `=` should be `==`, but even then this won't work at all.  It needs to loop, and on each iteration request input, and only stop looping once the user enters "stop".  I have no idea what the -3 is about, and `a[i]` will return a char, not a string.

Comment: I couldn't do it

Comment: couldn't do what? Show what you tried and what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Within your function (I suppose it's the application entry point):

```
while (true)
{
    String line = Console.ReadLine();

    if ((line == null) || (line.ToLowerInvariant() == "stop"))
        break;

    // implement your logic here... for example, if you want to print
    // a word at once even if the user entered multiples:

    String[] split = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (Int32 i = 0 ; i < split.Length; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(split[i]);
}
```